# AndroidでNanoHTTPD.javaの記載方法

Tags: android, eclipse, nanohttpd

Eclise:Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
minSdkVersion : 19
targetSdkVersion: 19

eclipseを使ってAndroid上でNanoHTTPDを動かそうとしています。
http://komamitsu.hatenablog.com/entry/20120223/1330013934
のサイトを参考して作成しています。

MainActivity.javaと同じフォルダ位置にNanoHTTPD.javaを置いていますが、
「宣言されたパッケージ "" が、予想されているパッケージ "com.xxxx.yyyy"(仮) に一致しません」とのエラーが出ます。
 import com.xxx.yyyy
を先頭に置くとエラーは無くなりますが、正しい方法なのでしょうか？

他のサイトでも確認していますが、そのような記載をしなさいと掲載しているサイトはありませんでした。
気持ち悪いのでご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NanoHTTPD.javaのファイルの冒頭で宣言されているパッケージ名が、存在しない、または

```
package fi.iki.elonen;
```

などとなっている（[参考](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fi/iki/elonen/NanoHTTPD.java)）のであれば、これを

```
package com.xxx.yyyy;
```

にしてみてください。

Javaでは原則としてパッケージ名とフォルダ構造が一致しているので、MainActivity と同じパスにNanoHTTPD.javaを持ってきたのであれば、NanoHTTPD.javaのパッケージ宣言もそれに応じて修正することになります。